# strange loop logic in c++

Tags: loops, c++11, logic

```
std::cout << "How many turns do you want to do?" << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::string turnsDefined;
    std::cin >> turnsDefined;
    //std::cin.sync();
    bool hasPassed = false;
    int objectSizeIniti = 0;
    int objectSizePost = 0;
    for(char c : turnsDefined){
        objectSizeIniti++;
    }
    bool boolForCharIsDigi[objectSizeIniti];
    for(bool _b : boolForCharIsDigi){
        _b = false;
    }

while(hasPassed != true){
        for(char c : turnsDefined){
            if(isdigit(c) == 0){
                boolForCharIsDigi[objectSizePost] = false;
            }else if (isdigit(c) != 0){
                boolForCharIsDigi[objectSizePost] = true;
            }
            bool allTrue = false;
            for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi)/sizeof(boolForCharIsDigi[0]); i++){
                if(boolForCharIsDigi[i] == false){
                    allTrue = false;
                    std::cin >> turnsDefined;
                    std::cout << "You may only use numbers to define the amount of turns. No decimals either." << std::endl << std::endl;
                    break;
                }else if(boolForCharIsDigi[i] == true){
                    allTrue = true;
                    hasPassed = true
                }
            }
        }
        objectSizePost++;
    }
```

I'm trying to comprehend why the above code acts so strangely.

What I'm trying to do:

I'm getting the input and testing if it consists only of digits. If it does, it simply passes the loop (sets the variable the w-loop is checking for to true). If the input does contain chars other than digits, it requests another input and warns the user.

What Happens: It randomly needs a number of inputs to actually accept a "only numbers" one. Overall the whole program just acts randomly.

Comment: Did you try to debug it in order to check the problem? If you try to debug step-by-step you can easily find the cause of the problem.

Comment: `while(hasPassed != true)` makes me wince.

Comment: @Jepessen That's what I did. Didn't help though since I simply couldn't figure out the logic. It iterated really strange...

Comment: @FredLarson I'll change it. But please don't comment just to say that.

Answer (score 3):

> What I'm trying to do:
>   I'm getting the input and testing if it consists only of digits. If it
>   does, it simply passes the loop (sets the variable the w-loop is
>   checking for to true). If the input does contain chars other than
>   digits, it requests another input and warns the user.

Skipping the debugging part, I suggest you should have [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) :

```
if( std::all_of( turnsDefined.begin(), turnsDefined.end(), ::isdigit ) )
{
   // Correct input 
}

else
{
  // Warn the user, re-enter stuff   
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your (working) answer. However I'd also like to find out what I did wrong in my original code.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, the for loop that initializes 'boolForCharIsDigi' never updates the actual array:

```
for(bool _b : boolForCharIsDigi){
    _b = false;
}
```

The problem is that _b is a temp variable. You need to make it a reference like this:

```
for(bool& _b : boolForCharIsDigi){
    _b = false;
}
```

There may be other problems, but this one sprang into my eyes.. ;-)